# how to skip nan in for loop dict items

Tags: python, arrays

i have 2 dictionaries one named data_val and the second one named neg.

```
data_val
{'Ancolmekar': array([0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0.5]),
 'Cidurian': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'Dayeuhkolot': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Hantap': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Kertasari': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'Meteolembang': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Sapan': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}
neg
{'Ancolmekar': -1.0,
 'Cidurian': -1.0,
 'Dayeuhkolot': -1.0,
 'Hantap': -1.0,
 'Kertasari': -1.0,
 'Meteolembang': -1.0,
 'Sapan': -1.0}
```

i want to make the data the less or equal in neg values to 0 except Nan. i want the nan values is still there.

my expectation for data_val is like this :

```
{'Ancolmekar': array([0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0.0]),
 'Cidurian': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'Dayeuhkolot': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Hantap': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Kertasari': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'Meteolembang': array([nan, nan, nan, ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 'Sapan': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}
```

and this is my code. my code make the nan values to 0

```
for key, ch_vals in data_val.items():
    if key in neg:
        data_val[key] = [1 if val <= neg[key] else 0 for val in ch_vals]
    else:
        data_val[key] = [-1] * len(ch_vals)
```

i hope anyone can help me. thanks before

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: ** you shouldn't be using list comprehensions here**. Use *numpy*, you already have numpy arrays

Comment: @DYZ Turns out when I checked again my code was correct. thank you